# Pythonでレジスタ動作を模倣したい

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで32ビットレジスタの動作を疑似することは出来ますか？

```
EAX = AX + AH,AL
AX  = AH + AL
```

当然、ALはAHに桁上がりするみたいな。

C++では以下のような宣言で、疑似できるかと思うんですが、Pythonでどうでしょうか？

```
union REG{
    DWORD e;
    struct{
        WORD x,xh;;
    };
    struct{
        BYTE l,h;
    };
};

REG regA;
```

Comment: こういうのを調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [codypierce/pyemu](https://github.com/codypierce/pyemu), [cemu 0.5](https://pypi.org/project/cemu/)

Comment: 8086 で `AL` を演算対象にしたとき `AH` は変化しません (桁上がりしません) ので誤解なきよう。 `AL=81h` のとき `ADD AL,AL` の結果は `AL=02h` で `AH` は無変化です。

Comment: 桁上がりと言うのは間違いでした。regA.l=0x01  regA.e << 8 のような場合でした。

Answer (score 1):

> C++では以下のような宣言で、疑似できるかと思う

提示されたコードは単に32bitデータの一部を16bitまたは8bit単位で取得・設定できると言うだけのものなので、それと同等のことであれば、プロパティを使って似たようなことはできます。

```
class REG:
  def __init__(self):
    self.e = 0
  @property
  def x(self):
    return self.e & 0xFFFF
  @property
  def xh(self):
    return (self.e >> 16) & 0xFFFF
  @property
  def l(self):
    return self.e & 0xFF
  @property
  def h(self):
    return (self.e >> 8) & 0xFF
  @x.setter
  def x(self, val):
    self.e = (self.e & 0xFFFF0000) | (val & 0xFFFF)
  @xh.setter
  def xh(self, val):
    self.e = (self.e & 0xFFFF) | ((val & 0xFFFF) << 16)
  @l.setter
  def l(self, val):
    self.e = (self.e & 0xFFFFFF00) | (val & 0xFF)
  @h.setter
  def h(self, val):
    self.e = (self.e & 0xFFFF00FF) | ((val & 0xFF) << 8)

r = REG()
r.e = 0x1234ABCD
print(hex(r.e)) #-> 0x1234abcd
r.x = 0x5678
print(hex(r.e), hex(r.x)) #-> x12345678 0x5678
r.xh = 0x90EF
print(hex(r.e), hex(r.xh)) #-> 0x90ef5678 0x90ef
r.l = 0x12
print(hex(r.e), hex(r.l)) #-> 0x90ef5612 0x12
r.h = 0xAB
print(hex(r.e), hex(r.h)) #-> 0x90efab12 0xab
```